# Overly complex expression to calculate the change in a Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to find the log change in a series in a Pandas DataFrame (ie the arithmetic change between one point and the next). Although this code works, it seems overly convoluted; surely I'm doing something bad and there is a simpler way?

`df['Change'] = (lambda x: x.sub(x.shift(1)))(df['stat'].map(lambda x: math.log(x)))`

Thanks!

Comment: Well, the first thing that jumps out at me is that the second `lambda` is unnecessary and slows things down. You could just replace it with `math.log`, but there's almost certainly a better option with vectorized operations. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with Pandas to vectorize this properly.

Comment: Instead of using the first `lambda`, it seems simpler to save `x = df['stat'].map(math.log)` and then do `df['Change'] = x.sub(x.shift(1))` as a separate line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy (vectorized) logarithm with panda's [diff](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
>>> df['Change'] = np.log(df['stat']).diff()
```

Comment: So you *can* just `np.log` that thing.